# How to print an Excel Spreadsheet as Grayscale?

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing

I would like to print my filled cells in a different color to match the rest of my document. The filled cells contain green background and blue font. I want the cells to automatically print to grey background and black font. I do not want to have to go through my document and manually change the font and shading.

Is it possible to print the file as grayscale? Or, could someone provide me with a macro or code that would solve this problem?

Comment: What happens if you print using grey scale?

Comment: you could have a macro that would toggle the fill before and after printing. Is this something you would consider a solution?

Comment: I want the document to always show the green shade and blue font. I want the print version to always show the grey fill and the black font. I would consider anything that would allow me to do this.

Comment: Have you tried conditional formatting?

Comment: I have. The problem with conditional formatting is the cells will change from the green color to the grey color and stay that way after text is inserted. I want the input cells to always be green and just grey when they are printed.

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps:

1. Select your Printer and then click on *Printer Properties*. (Right now, you can see the preview shows our sheet in color).

   [image: Print Preview shown in Color]
2. In *Paper/Quality* Tab, change the *Color* Setting to *Black & White*.

   [image: Printer Properties]
3. As you can see, the preview turns to Grayscale and the sheet would print out in Gray background and black font.

   [image: Print Preview shown in Black & White]

Comment: There is no Printer properties option under Print in excel 2007. You need to say what to do in this circumstance.